# How to seek on a certain tab using TabHost

Tags: android, view, tabs, android-tabhost

I'm using TabHost and I have four tabs. When I start the related activity I want that the second tab is selected, and not the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder how you did not looked at this in Google Docs.

Anyways below is the answer.

```
  tabHost.setCurrentTab(index); // pass 1 if you want second tab to be selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

Set current Tab to : mTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning, use `tabHost.setCurrentTab(index)`, for exemple:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
tabHost.setCurrentTab(2)

TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
tabHost.addTab(... ...)

TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
tabHost.addTab(... ...)
```

Good luck..